# no resolver defined to resolve s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

All my xml files are stored in a AWS S3, I want to show them via my website :

Nginx conf:

```
location ~ \.xml$ {

    proxy_pass https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/sitemap$request_uri;

}
```

But I get a 502 and log says

```
[error] 13295#13295: *26 no resolver defined to resolve s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

If I define a resolver like

```
resolver s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
```

I get

```
[error] 14430#14430: *7 s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out),
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
location ~ \.xml$ {

    rewrite ^ /<bucket>/sitemap$request_uri break;
    proxy_pass https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
}
```

Comment: No but it works well on production env with us, do you have any idea why?

Comment: No! For me this did some strange redirect, ended up having to handle that so as not to be redirected to s3. But now I think about it, that could've been since initially CloudFront was not forwarding the Host header.

Comment: @me987654323 Can you provide the source? I'm getting same error.

Answer (score 6):

The AWS DNS is [*likely* at `10.0.0.2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html#AmazonDNS) in your VPC (it's the base CIDR plus two).

Add [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) and [`resolver_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver_timeout):

```
location ~ \.xml$ {
    resolver         10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    proxy_pass https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/sitemap$request_uri;
}
```

Note: In EC2 Classic the [AWS DNS server is located at `172.16.0.23`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#amazon-dns-server).

Answer (score 1):

Your resolver in this instance would be your local or external DNS server you would use to resolve dns names, not the s3 url.

Comment: I tried DNS public (IPv4), public and private IP, nothing work... @d_turner